# Bind an image path to image in UWP ListView item

Tags: c#, listview, binding, uwp

Trying to bind my `ImagePath` string to the image element in a List named `BusinessLineList` via Image.Source and `UriSource`. When I hard code one image path in XAML, it works, but not when bound to the `ImagePath` property.

Here's the model:

```
public class BusinessLinesModel 

    {
        public string ImagePath { get; }
        public string ProductType { get; }
        public int NumPending { get; }
        public double DollarAmount { get; }
        public int NumInforceYTD { get; }
        public int ID { get; }


        public BusinessLinesModel(int id, string imagePath, string productType, int numPending, double dollarAmount, int numInforceYTD)
        {
            ID = id;
            ImagePath = imagePath;
            ProductType = productType;
            NumPending = numPending;
            DollarAmount = dollarAmount;
            NumInforceYTD = numInforceYTD;
        }

    }
```

Here's the ViewModel code:

```
    private AgentsModel _selectedAgent;
    public AgentsModel SelectedAgent
    {
        get { return _selectedAgent; }
        set
        {

            _selectedAgent = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedAgent)));

            IsAgentSelected = Visibility.Visible;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsAgentSelected)));


            int i = SelectedAgent.ID;

            BusinessLineList = new List<BusinessLinesModel>();

            BusinessLineList.Add(new BusinessLinesModel(i, "Assets/lifebuoy2.png", "Life", i * i + i, i * 83.22, i * 7 + 2));
            BusinessLineList.Add(new BusinessLinesModel(i, "Assets/get-money.png", "Annuities", i * i + i, i * 83.22, i * 7 + 2));
            BusinessLineList.Add(new BusinessLinesModel(i, "Assets/old-man-walking-with-a-crutch.png", "LTC", i * i + i, i * 83.22, i * 7 + 2));
            BusinessLineList.Add(new BusinessLinesModel(i, "Assets/wheelchair2.png", "Disability", i * i + i, i * 83.22, i * 7 + 2));
            BusinessLineList.Add(new BusinessLinesModel(i, "Assets/link-symbol.png", "Linked Benefit", i * i + i, i * 83.22, i * 7 + 2));

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(BusinessLineList)));


            IsBusinessLineSelected = Visibility.Collapsed;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsBusinessLineSelected)));
        }
    }
```

Here's the XAML:

```
                            <ListView x:Name="listView1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CasesListModelTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding BusinessLineList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBusinessLine, Mode=TwoWay}" Visibility="{Binding IsAgentSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
```

And here's the ItemTemplate in XAML:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CasesListModelTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="10" Width="290" Height="100" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Margin="0,10,0,0" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition, TopPosition, BottomPosition" Width="75" Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Image.Source>
                    <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImagePath}"/>
                    <!--Hard-coding this in line above works: "Assets/lifebuoy2.png"-->
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
            <            </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, add `ms-appx:///` like this

```
"ms-appx:///Assets/lifebuoy2.png"
```

At second, you can setup `ImageSource` directly:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks — your first suggestion fixed it! Could you explain what the `"ms-appx:///"` is and does? (I couldn't seem to get your second answer to work.)

Comment: About `ms-appx` you can find more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242760)